# 0 rows updated while using update query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, dml

When I am trying to update a column with character datatype using update statement. It says 0 rows update and does not throw any error. As the number of columns are much i tried using where clause using specific column out of it...where it updates the row.

Issue is when all the columns are used to alter the value, it gives back 0 rows updated. I have to automate it in vba code/tool  so that it could update using all the rows. I identified the columns using which the value is not being updated but there is no error return.

It only says:

`0 rows updated`.

But what is wrong with that specific column(datatype...decimal).

Please help. I have searched whole internet but no results.

Comment: show the query and some sample data

Comment: this is the identified column which i not letting the update. Update keyfigures2 set "Company Name" = 'chem5' where  "Gross Profit Margin" = 0.198871996076508;     (P.S:  There is no Primary Key on the table)

Comment: Please show the SQL query you used to have this `0 updates`...

Comment: Here it is sir. Adding more to the query.      Update keyfigures2 set "Company Name" = 'chem5' where  "Gross Profit Margin" = 0.198871996076508 AND "EBITDA (Reported)" = 365 AND "EBITDA (Adj.)" = 583 AND "EBITDA (Adj.) Margin" = 0.142962236390387 AND "EBIT (Reported)" = 153;

Comment: There are very few situations where a table wont have a primary key. Usually it is as a result of bad modelling, laziness or ignorance of relational principles. What can be seen of your query suggests that PK is very possible in this situation and would likely solve your problem. Sort the design and the rest will follow.

Comment: You get results when run select count(*) from keyfigures2  where  "Gross Profit Margin" = 0.198871996076508 AND "EBITDA (Reported)" = 365 AND "EBITDA (Adj.)" = 583 AND "EBITDA (Adj.) Margin" = 0.142962236390387 AND "EBIT (Reported)" = 153;  but no updates when run the other statement?

Comment: @MiloBellano I am getting count as 0 when using the above select statement you mentioned

Comment: @BriteSponge Thanks for your response. The thing is that i have a table which contains few columns having duplicate values as well as null values. all i need is that i should be able to edit and update any value in any column i want including duplicates.  Can you please suggest any alternative

Comment: If count is 0 it means you don't have anything to update..... no situation with that where condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update a specific value in your database and only that one, you may have a rounding issue. This mean the value you see is not the exact value stored.

So you may try to update it with a specific range.

1. First select what you want to update:

   ```
   select rowid from table_1 
    where val_x between <x>-<upsilon> and <x>+<upsilon>;
   ```
2. Update **if you have only one value**;

   ```
   update table_1 set val_x = <new_val>
    where val_x between <x>-0.001 and <x>+0.001
   ;
   ```

(otherwise, if more than 1 value, decrease `<upsilon>` to `0.0001`,  etc.)

Hope it helps